# Toggle child process window visibility in Visual C++ without relaunching the child

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, child-process, createprocess

Using Visual Studio 2017.

I use

> siStartInfo.dwFlags &= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
>
> siStartInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

to create a child process (through CreateProcess()) with a hidden window.  It works perfectly.

What I would like, if at all possible, is to be able to **toggle** the visibility status of the child process' window, post-creation, from the main program on demand (with a press of a button, for example).  I want to control the child process' window visibility without relaunching it through CreateProcess().

Modifying the child process code is not an option - it can be many different programs with not necessarily available source code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;` need use

Comment: unclear how `visual-studio` related to all this. and child process can ignore startup info at all.

Comment: You will have to find the child process window and show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know a unique window class or title of the child process, you can use [`FindWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) to find that window.

For a more generic approach, use [`EnumWindows()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) to enumerate all top-level windows. For each window call [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx) to check if it belongs to the child process.

Call [`ShowWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) to toggle visibility.

Comment: If the spawned app is single-threaded (or at least, the window in question belongs to the main thread), consider using [`EnumThreadWindows()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633495.aspx) instead of `EnumWindows()`+`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`.  `CreateProcess()` returns the thread ID of the main thread of the new process.